# how to add a widget in shared preference

Tags: dart, flutter

I have built an application with intro sliders that appear after the user log in.
I want the intro sliders to appear only for the first user login and not every login user does.

How can I save all the widget in the `SharedPreference`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to save a `Widget` in `SharedPreferences`. 
You can try this simple logic.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    bool isFirstTime = prefs.getBool("first_time") ?? true;
    if (isFirstTime) {
      // it is first time app opening you can show your intro part
      // also call setState() from here to reflect changes in the build method.
      prefs.setBool("first_time", false);
    } else {
      // it is regular opening of the app.
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't save widgets in SharedPreferences. You can save Boolean value to show intro widgets or not .By default set the Boolean of the variable to true means you can show intro slides, then after showing slides successful then make that Boolean to false. such that from next time it won't appear.

Comment: `By defaults Boolean is true` -- I'm sorry my dear friend this is not Java.

Comment: I mean to say make the Boolean value of that variable default to true. Then change it once done with intro slides. Any how I edited answer to reflect my thoughts.